# Override default harakiri duration of uwsgi in Flask/Python

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

For most requests/routes a standard harakiri value of 15s or 30s will be fine.

But a few endpoints are long running (such as when generating reports) and I want the client to wait synchronously while they are prepared and returned.

Can I set a default harakiri value in uwsgi.ini and then override it in flask/python, either in code or by using a decorator in flask?

A previous answer shows how to do this using uWSGI config/routes but I would prefer to keep these special cases separate from the standard uWSGI timeout configuration. [uWSGI - Different Harakiri Timeout for Django Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27758999/uwsgi-different-harakiri-timeout-for-django-admin)

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if project you're writing could be written in different way, then you can do the generating process. It's one of many options:

Create a link which will fire up backend process. After user page refresh, there will be wording that generating is in progress. Then you have two options, first is to tell end-user that: We will notify you when will finish and send him some kind of even email notification, or simplest one, where you do nothing, but just only checking if specific process is running in the background on your machine and according to answer yes/no, display a link to a file or leave a message that he must still wait, because process hasn't been ended.

In case I described, every long generating will be separated from HTTP layer. You can even mix it with your method if you can predict when it's heading to timeout.

Hope I explained it enough.

Comment: Thanks @turkus, that is probably the approach I will need to take if I cannot dynamically override the default timeout value.