# How to define different harakiri timeout on different route?

Tags: uwsgi

I want to define different harakiri timeout on different route path because I want to allow long timeout of specific URI.

Ex:

- URI `/management/` -> timeout 300
- URI `/report/` -> timeout 300
- URI `/list/` -> timeout 30

If I set up 2 route URI, it will also overwrite default timeout.

```
[uwsgi]
route     = ^/report/ harakiri:300
route     = ^/management/ harakiri:300
route-run = harakiri:30
```

All URI timeout will be `300`, the default timeout is not `30`.

I expect it will apply different harakiri timeout, but not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [uWSGI - Different Harakiri Timeout for Django Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27758999/uwsgi-different-harakiri-timeout-for-django-admin)

Comment: I had tried the solution by the post, but still not working. My config will set route on 2 URI as special case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem on my environment. Answer by my self, hope to help you guys.

If you pretty sure your configuration is correct, but the uwsgi route is not working. Please take a look on your `uwsgi.log`

```
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
```

There is error by uwsgi for the `pcre` package

I had fix it by follow steps, env: Ubuntu14.04

1. `apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev`
2. reinstall your `uwsgi`
3. launch your uwsgi again
4. make sure the error in `uwsgi.log` is gone